# PowerShell SendMessage Unicode Text

Tags: powershell, api, unicode, sendmessage

I have successfully used SendMessage api to send text to Notepad, both in CharSet.ANSI and CharSet.Unicode.

Besides Notepad, I also use Notepad2.  I was able to send text to Notepad2 as CharSet.ANSI but when I try to send text as CharSet.Unicode, it only sends 1 character.

And yes, on my Notepad2 settings, I have changed the default encoding to UTF8 and UTF16.  I tried both so that when Powershell starts a new instance of it, in code below, the editor (Scintilla) is set to the correct encoding.

Any ideas?  I read on another site to also look into SendDlgItemMessage, instead of SendMessage.

I pieced most of these codes from several sites together.

```
#https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/Windows/PowerShell/examples/WinAPI/writing-into-notepad-with-SendMessage
set-strictMode -version latest

$code = 
@'
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, EntryPoint = "FindWindowExW")]  public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, String lpszClass, String lpszWindow);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, EntryPoint = "SendMessage")]    public static extern IntPtr SendMessage         (IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, string lParam);
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, EntryPoint = "SendMessageA")]   public static extern IntPtr SendMessage_Ansi    (IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, string lParam);
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, EntryPoint = "SendMessageW")]   public static extern IntPtr SendMessage_Unicode (IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, string lParam);
'@

$myAPI = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $code -Name myAPI -Namespace Win32 -PassThru

$App        = "Notepad.exe"             #"Notepad       Notepad2"
$MyClass    = "Edit"                    #"Edit          Scintilla"

$notepad_1 = start-process -passThru -FilePath $App
$notepad_2 = start-process -passThru -FilePath $App
$notepad_3 = start-process -passThru -FilePath $App

# PURPOSE: Wait for application windows to be created.
$null = $notepad_1.WaitForInputIdle()
$null = $notepad_2.WaitForInputIdle()
$null = $notepad_3.WaitForInputIdle()

$hwndNotepad_1 = $notepad_1.MainWindowHandle
$hwndNotepad_2 = $notepad_2.MainWindowHandle
$hwndNotepad_3 = $notepad_3.MainWindowHandle

$hwndEdit_1    = $myAPI::FindWindowEx($hwndNotepad_1, [IntPtr]::Zero, $MyClass  , $null)
$hwndEdit_2    = $myAPI::FindWindowEx($hwndNotepad_2, [IntPtr]::Zero, $MyClass  , $null)
$hwndEdit_3    = $myAPI::FindWindowEx($hwndNotepad_3, [IntPtr]::Zero, $MyClass  , $null)

$UnicodeMessage = "ĐĐĐĐảảảảả"

#Set-Variable WM_SETTEXT -Option Constant -Value 0X000C
$WM_SETTEXT = 0X000C

$null          =         $myAPI::SendMessage($hwndEdit_1, [int]$WM_SETTEXT, $UnicodeMessage.Length, "1 " + $UnicodeMessage)
$null          =    $myAPI::SendMessage_Ansi($hwndEdit_2, [int]$WM_SETTEXT, $UnicodeMessage.Length, "2 " + $UnicodeMessage)
$null          = $myAPI::SendMessage_Unicode($hwndEdit_3, [int]$WM_SETTEXT, $UnicodeMessage.Length, "3 " + $UnicodeMessage)
```

Comment: Try to use this PInvoke signature for Unicode: `[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, nuint wParam, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lParam);`

Comment: zett42, when I added that code into the process, it failed at the Add-Type -MemberDefinition. Am I missing something else since MarshalAs is also added in your code?

Comment: This one succeeds with `Add-Type`: `[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)] public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lParam);`.

Comment: Thanks Zett42. It did not error out this time.  However, still sending only one character.  It is weird, charset.Ansi works but Unicode and Auto send only 1 character.

Comment: It might be that the window procedure of Notepad2 isn't Unicode. So it tries to interpret the UTF-16 LE string as ANSI, which would explain why only 1 char is received (for UTF-16 LE every 2nd byte is 0, when you send characters in the ASCII range). Call `IsWindowUnicode(hwnd)` to check this. [See also](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180906-00/?p=99665).

Comment: Sorry Zett42, I just started to learn PowerShell.  Do I need to declare anything before IsWindowUnicode?  It errored out when I ran it

Comment: $myAPI = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $code -Name myAPI -Namespace Win32 -PassThru

$notepad_1 = start-process -passThru -FilePath $App

$null = $notepad_1.WaitForInputIdle()
$hwndNotepad_1 = $notepad_1.MainWindowHandle
#$T = $myAPI::IsWindowUnicode($hwndEdit_1)
#$T

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247607/discussion-between-zett42-and-liquidmetal).

Answer (score 0):

I would like to thank Zett42 who has helped to resolve this SendMessage with Unicode question.

By changing his code a bit with the following values, it resolved my question.

LPUTF8Str 48
A pointer to a UTF-8 encoded string.

LPWStr 21
A 2-byte, null-terminated Unicode character string. You cannot use the LPWStr value with an unmanaged string unless the string was created by using the unmanaged CoTaskMemAlloc function.

This is Zett42's original code:

```
Add-Type: [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)] public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lParam);
```